# Drag sprite for svg elements on IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to show the drag sprite for svg elements in IE/Edge ?

Example:

This one can be dragged without problems

```
<img draggable="true" src="file.jpg" />
```

This one doesn't show the drag sprite

```
<img draggable="true" src="file.svg" />
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/akotb/pen/WGNOXv

Also it doesn't work if the div you are dragging has a direct (or indirect) child that use svg symbols

```
<div draggable="true"> <svg><use xlink:href="#circle" /></svg></div>
```

updated the demo with that example as well

Comment: your first div with the svg background works... what's the issue?

Comment: i need to make it work with svgs, all my assets are svgs., it also doesn't work if the svg image is a child of the dragged element

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you an advice which makes your SVG works, however I recommend you also read the following documents as well:

Let's assume this is your HTML part

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

this is your CSS styles

```
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#div1, #div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

we may add some Javascript code as well that makes a bit easier to handle for cross-browser compatibility

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

together we can make this http://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/QKjgAo

More documents :

1- [Cross Browser HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/)

2- [Using HTML5’s Native Drag and Drop API](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-native-drag-and-drop-api/)

3- [HTML 5 drag and drop API](http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/)

Update:

> Since IE is a bit tricky to get that to work with SVG draggable I update this post with another solution which works from IE8+ and also touch-screens. One of the light libraries that could help is interact.js. This is solution https://jsfiddle.net/mhadaily/pkewdttr/ and you can see it works in IE8+ and other browsers very smooth. Please check interactjs.io website to more documentation.

If you need more help please ask me.

Comment: Yes Tested, perfectly works, Edge:https://s14.postimg.io/9ptpz5ttt/Screen_Shot_2016_09_11_at_1_02_38_AM.jpg  and IE11: https://s14.postimg.io/gubj87135/Screen_Shot_2016_09_11_at_1_02_52_AM.jpg as you see in the images above, the SVG image is inside the box which I have dragged that there.

Comment: This doesn't work in IE 11 (or you didn't understand the question. Check again).

Comment: yup, that doesn't work (or answers a different question)

Comment: Like I said I meant to give you an example to show, you'll need to do manual hit testing if you want to support drag and drop on SVG elements. If you're interested, you can take a look at drag-drop.dart. It's a library of mine that supports cross-browser drag and drop on SVG. here is the link https://github.com/danschultz/drag-drop.dart if it helps please let me know. There is no other way as IE doesn't support  HTML5 drag and drop so a library that supports cross-browser will help in this case. I have mentioned 3 in the post as well.

Comment: Hello from malaysia! :D